# ASP.NET CheckBoxFor generates hidden field messes up ajax submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

So by default `@Html.CheckBoxFor` is going to generate a hidden field after the original field, something like

```
<input name="xxx" id="xxx" type="checkbox" .... data-val="true" value="true"/>
<input name="xxx" type="hidden" value="false"/>
```

When I do ajax submit with `$(form).serialize()` the post body would contain two xxx fields if the checkbox is checked. (`xxx=true&&xxx=false`) This is expected. But then `ModelState.IsValid` returns false and the error is

> System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Boolean' failed because no type converter can convert between these types

How can I fix this??

Update:
It is happening to my WebAPI controller, I am doing the regular model binding with

```
[HttpPost]
public void MyMethod(MyModel model)
{
    if ( !ModelState.IsValid )
        throw new HttpResponseException( HttpStatusCode.BadRequest );
}
```

Comment: If its really an issue, forget about the helper and just output a plain checkbox using `<input type="checkbox" name="xxx" @if(Model.xxx){<text>checked="checked"</text>} />`. But how are you binding your model in the controller? I would have thought the default binder would handle this correctly.

Comment: @Rhumborl that's what I thought too. But it looks like the WebApi binder is not functioning the same way as the MVC one. I am doing public void MyMethod(MyModel model) by the way

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC 4's WebAPI does not bind check boxes correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996285/asp-net-mvc-4s-webapi-does-not-bind-check-boxes-correctly)

Comment: @Rhumborl that question only provided a workaround without providing the reason. I still would like to find out the reason behind it